# Email text message

Tags: java, email, sms

I am writing a java application to send emails, but I would also like it to be able to send them to people as text messages. I know I can make them text messages by adding a @vtext (for verizon) or @tmobile (for tmobile) along with all of the other types of carriers, but I dont want to have to ask the user their phone carrier to be able to send them a text message.

Is there a way to send a email to just a phone number (without @vtext or any dynamic text) and have them recieve it?

Thanks.

Comment: IMHO you'll have to use a GSM modem to do that, or maybe use one of the free SMS services on the web

Comment: Im hoping someone knows of a good free Java API i can leverage. I would be okay with leveraging a SMS service online too though.

Comment: We use Twilio (http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-sms) to send our SMS messages.  It's not free, but domestically (US) it's only a penny or so.  International is a bit more expensive, around 7 cents per message.

Comment: Really looking for either a free service or a API which provides this. I may be sending enough text messages that a penny per message might eventually matter.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you just have to send an SMS to a phone number. At least in Germany one of two possibilities will happen:

- The receiver will get the SMS send directly to his phone. If its a
  mobile phone its business as usual. If its not a mobile phone the
  receiver has to activate this function via his device, so that the
  carrier knows its able to receive SMS.
- The receiver will get a call from an automatic service, reading the
  SMS text with a synthetic speach. This happens when the receiver's
  device is not a mobile phone and no SMS registration has been done by
  the receiver.

I don't know how it works in other countries, but I think it will be similar.

Comment: Wanting to send a email as a SMS. The email needs to have a @Something for it to send so just the phone number wont work. I tried doing <phone-number>@gmail.com but it always says that the email failed to send.